# why == and != weird logic happen?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul role="abc">
<li class role="presentation"><a href="#tab-aaa" data-toggle="tab">aaa </a></li>
<li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-bbb" data-toggle="tab">bbb </a></li>
<li class role="presentation"><a href="#tab-ccc" data-toggle="tab">ccc </a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('ul[role="abc"] li').hasClass('active')){
    if($(this).find('a').attr('href') != '#tab-bbb') { //problem here
        alert ("bbb is active");
    }
}
</script>
```

From code above, see comment out `//problem here` there

Supposedly code should be `if($(this).find('a').attr('href') == '#tab-bbb')` then only will pop up alert right? But when i use `==`, it fail to pop up alert.

why I change it become "!=" sign then only will pop up alert?

Comment: `this` is the window in your code. `$(this).find('a')` always finds the first link on the page. [`this` is not jQuery magic.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) Also, turn on [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: i see. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `if` is just testing whether *any* of the `li` has the `active` class. But it doesn't set `this` to that `li`, so you can't use `$(this).find()` to find something within it.

You can combine this all into a single selector:

```
if ($("ul[role='abc'] li.active a[href='#tab-bbb']").length != 0) {
    alert("bbb is active");
}
```

Comment: may i know why .length != 0 ?

Comment: `.length` returns the number of elements that matched the selector. If there's an active bbb, the length will be at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since cannot use $(this) , i work around the code finally come out this solution and it works.

```
var href4 = $('ul[role="abc"] li.active a').attr('href');
if (href4 == "#tab-bbb"){
    alert ("bbb is active");
}
```